# Tumblr get Like Button status with Infinite Scroll

Tags: button, scroll, tumblr, infinite, social-media-like

I would like to request the Like Button status of each post (by ID) that is appended by Infinite Scroll.

```
<li class="post text" id="{PostID}">
```

The [Tumblr Documentation](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#like_and_reblog_buttons) provides this method of checking the status of a Like Button for individual posts:

> **Tumblr.LikeButton.get_status_by_page(n)**
>   Description: Call this function after requesting a new page of Posts. Takes the page number that was just loaded as an integer.

Finally, here is the Infinite Scroll script (Proto.jp modified by Cody Sherman):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var tumblrAutoPager = {
    url: "http://proto.jp/",
    ver: "0.1.7",
    rF: true,
    gP: {},
    pp: null,
    ppId: "",
    LN: location.hostname,
    init: function() {
        if ($("autopagerize_icon") || navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPhone') != -1) return;
        var tAP = tumblrAutoPager;
        var p = 1;
        var lh = location.href;
        var lhp = lh.lastIndexOf("/page/");
        var lht = lh.lastIndexOf("/tagged/");
        if (lhp != -1) {
            p = parseInt(lh.slice(lhp + 6));
            tAP.LN = lh.slice(7, lhp);
        } else if (lht != -1) {
            tAP.LN = lh.slice(7);
            if (tAP.LN.slice(tAP.LN.length - 1) == "/") tAP.LN = tAP.LN.slice(0, tAP.LN.length - 1);
        } else if ("http://" + tAP.LN + "/" != lh) {
            return;
        };
        var gPFncs = [];
        gPFncs[0] = function(aE) {
            var r = [];
            for (var i = 0, l = aE.length; i < l; i++) {
                if (aE[i].className == "autopagerize_page_element") {
                    r = gCE(aE[i]);
                    break;
                }
            }
            return r;
        };
        gPFncs[1] = function(aE) {
            var r = [];
            for (var i = 0, l = aE.length; i < l; i++) {
                var arr = aE[i].className ? aE[i].className.split(" ") : null;
                if (arr) {
                    for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
                        arr[j] == "post" ? r.push(aE[i]) : null;
                    }
                }
            }
            return r;
        };
        gPFncs[2] = function(aE) {
            var r = [];
            var tmpId = tAP.ppId ? [tAP.ppId] : ["posts", "main", "container", "content", "apDiv2", "wrapper", "projects"];
            for (var i = 0, l = aE.length; i < l; i++) {
                for (var j = 0; j < tmpId.length; j++) {
                    if (aE[i].id == tmpId[j]) {
                        r = gCE(aE[i]);
                        tAP.ppId = aE[i].id;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return r;
        };
        for (var i = 0; i < gPFncs.length; i++) {
            var getElems = gPFncs[i](document.body.getElementsByTagName('*'));
            if (getElems.length) {
                tAP.gP = gPFncs[i];
                tAP.pp = getElems[0].parentNode;
                break;
            }
        }

        function gCE(pElem) {
            var r = [];
            for (var i = 0, l = pElem.childNodes.length; i < l; i++) {
                r.push(pElem.childNodes.item(i))
            }
            return r;
        }
        if (!tAP.pp) {
            return;
        }
        sendRequest.README = {
            license: 'Public Domain',
            url: 'http://jsgt.org/lib/ajax/ref.htm',
            version: 0.516,
            author: 'Toshiro Takahashi'
        };
        function chkAjaBrowser() {
            var A, B = navigator.userAgent;
            this.bw = {
                safari: ((A = B.split('AppleWebKit/')[1]) ? A.split('(')[0].split('.')[0] : 0) >= 124,
                konqueror: ((A = B.split('Konqueror/')[1]) ? A.split(';')[0] : 0) >= 3.3,
                mozes: ((A = B.split('Gecko/')[1]) ? A.split(' ')[0] : 0) >= 20011128,
                opera: ( !! window.opera) && ((typeof XMLHttpRequest) == 'function'),
                msie: ( !! window.ActiveXObject) ? ( !! createHttpRequest()) : false
            };
            return (this.bw.safari || this.bw.konqueror || this.bw.mozes || this.bw.opera || this.bw.msie)
        }

        function createHttpRequest() {
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                return new XMLHttpRequest()
            } else {
                if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                    try {
                        return new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP')
                    } catch (B) {
                        try {
                            return new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP')
                        } catch (A) {
                            return null
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    return null
                }
            }
        };
        function sendRequest(E, R, C, D, F, G, S, A) {
            var Q = C.toUpperCase() == 'GET',
                H = createHttpRequest();
            if (H == null) {
                return null
            }
            if ((G) ? G : false) {
                D += ((D.indexOf('?') == -1) ? '?' : '&') + 't=' + (new Date()).getTime()
            }
            var P = new chkAjaBrowser(),
                L = P.bw.opera,
                I = P.bw.safari,
                N = P.bw.konqueror,
                M = P.bw.mozes;
            if (typeof E == 'object') {
                var J = E.onload;
                var O = E.onbeforsetheader
            } else {
                var J = E;
                var O = null
            }
            if (L || I || M) {
                H.onload = function() {
                    J(H);
                    H.abort()
                }
            } else {
                H.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (H.readyState == 4) {
                        J(H);
                        H.abort()
                    }
                }
            }
            R = K(R, D);
            if (Q) {
                D += ((D.indexOf('?') == -1) ? '?' : (R == '') ? '' : '&') + R
            }
            H.open(C, D, F, S, A);
            if ( !! O) {
                O(H)
            }
            B(H);
            H.send(R);
            function B(T) {
                if (!L || typeof T.setRequestHeader == 'function') {
                    T.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8')
                }
                return T
            }

            function K(X, V) {
                var Z = [];
                if (typeof X == 'object') {
                    for (var W in X) {
                        Y(W, X[W])
                    }
                } else {
                    if (typeof X == 'string') {
                        if (X == '') {
                            return ''
                        }
                        if (X.charAt(0) == '&') {
                            X = X.substring(1, X.length)
                        }
                        var T = X.split('&');
                        for (var W = 0; W < T.length; W++) {
                            var U = T[W].split('=');
                            Y(U[0], U[1])
                        }
                    }
                }

                function Y(b, a) {
                    Z.push(encodeURIComponent(b) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(a))
                }
                return Z.join('&')
            }
            return H
        }

        function addNextPage(oj) {
            if (oj.status == 404) {
                tAP.remainFlg = false;
                return;
            }
            var d = document.createElement("div");
            d.innerHTML = oj.responseText;
            var posts = tAP.gP(d.getElementsByTagName("*"));
            if (posts.length < 2) {
                tAP.rF = false;
                return;
            }
            d = document.createElement("div");
            d.className = "tumblrAutoPager_page_info";
            tAP.pp.appendChild(d);
            for (var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
                tAP.pp.appendChild(posts[i]);
            }
            var footer = $("footer");
            footer ? footer.parentNode.appendChild(footer) : null;
            tAP.rF = true;
        }
        watch_scroll();
        function watch_scroll() {
            var d = document.compatMode == "BackCompat" ? document.body : document.documentElement;
            var r = d.scrollHeight - d.clientHeight - (d.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop);
            if (r < d.clientHeight * 2 && tAP.rF) {
                tAP.rF = false;
                p++;
                sendRequest(addNextPage, "", "GET", "http://" + tAP.LN + "/page/" + p, true);
            }
            setTimeout(arguments.callee, 200);
        };
        function $(id) {
            return document.getElementById(id)
        }
    },
    switchAutoPage: function() {
        this.rF = !this.rF;
        var aE = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
        for (var i = 0, l = aE.length; i < l; i++) {
            if (aE[i].className == "tAP_switch") {
                aE[i].firstChild.nodeValue = this.rF ? "AutoPage[OFF]" : "AutoPage[ON]";
            }
        }
    }
};

window.addEventListener ? window.addEventListener('load', tumblrAutoPager.init, false) : window.attachEvent ? window.attachEvent("onload", tumblrAutoPager.init) : window.onload = tumblrAutoPager.init;

});
```

Any insight is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to do the trick!

```
            function addNextPage(oj) {
            if (oj.status == 404) {
                tAP.remainFlg = false;
                return;
            }
            var d = document.createElement("div");
            d.innerHTML = oj.responseText;
            var posts = tAP.gP(d.getElementsByTagName("*"));
            if (posts.length < 2) {
                tAP.rF = false;
                return;
            }
            d = document.createElement("div");
            d.className = "tumblrAutoPager_page_info";
            tAP.pp.appendChild(d);
            for (var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
                tAP.pp.appendChild(posts[i]);
            }
            var footer = $("footer");
            footer ? footer.parentNode.appendChild(footer) : null;
            tAP.rF = true;

            //Get Like Button status of newly appended page
            Tumblr.LikeButton.get_status_by_page(p);
        }
```